# Send two strings from fragment to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, android-fragmentactivity

I don't understand how to transfer data between two fragments. I've tried this:

```
public class Connection extends Fragment
{
 SendMessage sender;
 public interface SendMessage
{
 public void send(String one, String two);
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  //my data  
}
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    send = (SendMessage) getActivity();
}

private class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      if(message.equals("POS"))
      {
       sender.send(position,id);
      }
    }
  }
```

in the first fragment; in the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements      Connection.SendMessage
{
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {  
  //my code
 }

  @Override
  public void send(String one, String two) 
  {
   Map map = new Map();
   final Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
   bundle.putString("Position",one);
   bundle.putString("ID:",two);
   map.setArguments(bundle);
  }
}
```

and in the Map fragment(it need to receive this data):

```
public class Map extends Fragment
{
 public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.getArguments();

 if (bundle != null)
 {
  String pos = bundle.getString("Position");
  String id = bundle.getString("ID");
 }
  //then show this on googleMaps
 }
}
```

but I don't understand why this code doesn't work..could you help me? thanks...

Answer (score 2):

1) Please change your class name from Map.java to anything else. Because in java map is imported as java.util Package.

2)

```
Fragment map = new Fragment ();
   final Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
   bundle.putString("Position",one);
   bundle.putString("ID:",two);
   map.setArguments(bundle);
map.setArguments(arguments);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.item_detail_container, map).commit();
```

and in recieve

```
 Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null)
     {
      String pos = bundle.getString("Position");
      String id = bundle.getString("ID:"); (You miss : in ID)
     }
```

Comment: I've corrected it but I have the same problem..I have an interface with tab and I want to show this in the maps..but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Do This send fragment

```
String cid=id.getText().toString();
Fragment fr=new friendfragment();
FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("CID", cid);
fr.setArguments(args);

ft.commit();
```

Received fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
String strtext = getArguments().getString("CID");    
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
  }
```

Comment: sorry,where is content_frame?

Comment: it s like a intent method. when move to another fragment to get this values

Comment: so is the xml file associate with java file?

Comment: where your fragment xml id in java file

Comment: this code works in your project? So i don't pass data to MainActivity?

Comment: 1st learn  about fragment-activity,fragment,activity k i think your so confused

Comment: A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

Comment: I know it, i don't understand if the Fragment fr=new friendfragment();
FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("CID", cid);
fr.setArguments(args);

ft.commit();  is to put in MainActivity

Answer (score -1):

Well, firstly. Your receiving fragment is actually accessing an empty bundle. You are doing this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.getArguments();
```

Instead of:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
```

Secondly, a good way to communicate between two fragments is by using an interface. The interface communicates with the activity and the activity with the second fragment.
Here's google's tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Also, it doesn't seem like you are inflating any xml layout file for your Map Fragment or even adding it with FragmentTransaction after you have created it. Here is a short and sweet tutorial for that as well:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/12/programmatically-add-fragment.html